# CHARSET on column level in Mysql 5

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, mysql5

My app has a table that has two columns needing utf8 and others are latin. Latin ones does not contain non-latin characters by definition and utf8 ones may or may not contain utf8 ones. One utf8 column is indexed and other is not.

I have three questions:

Is mixing charsets on a column level a good practice?

If a row (on this table) contains only latin chars and no utf8 chars how are data storage and index size affected? Put another way, is a utf8 column data/index size same as latin without storing any utf8 text.

Quantitively how are data and index storage affected on utf8 columns with respect to latin?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

UTF-8 is a variable length encoding. Characters inside the [ASCII set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) will be encoded with one byte as in latin1; characters beyond that will be encoded using up to four bytes. A string consisting of ASCII characters will have the same length in UTF8 and latin1.

> Is mixing charsets on a column level a good practice?

I have never done this, and would tend to say no, as it complicates the database schema unnecessarily. While the database engine should be able to deal with it fine, I would *not* use mixed charsets out of storage considerations. The savings will be minimal at best.

The only valid reason to mix charsets that I can think of is the use of different collations for a specific sort order and/or case/accent sensitive/insensitive searching.

Comment: Pekka, 1 byte vs 4 bytes count for both storage and index? up to 4 bytes like Russian 2 bytes or Chinese 4 bytes and so? is there chart of these?

Comment: one more question, do german umlauts count for more than 1 byte because they are not in US-ASCII?